# Getting Net::ReadTimeout with #<socket:(closed)>, immediately when attempting to send action mail rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails 6.1, using action mailer.
Getting this error message, Completed 500 Internal Server Error in (X)ms

Net::ReadTimeout (Net::ReadTimeout with #socket:(closed)):

It doesn't matter which kind of email I send or how long it takes.
The only change between my production and development is that I updated my gems, which I only allowed for minor updates (2.5.1 ~> 2.5.2)

No clue where to look.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you figure out the issue?

Comment: Yes, did you figure out?

Comment: Having same issue on production currently, downgraded gems but i think its a issue with the server/connection

Comment: Having same issue!  Development/Staging env sends emails fine but getting the readtimeout in production environment.  Has anyone fixed this?

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into this same issue.  My Rails 6.1 app could send emails fine on the development server but would get Net::ReadTimeout errors on the production server.

The solution ended up being that the IP address of the production server needed to be added to our Email Exchange Relay server.

Answer (score 0):

You may see this error when the email settings to authenticate are changed. For example, if an admin adds an MFA requirement to all accounts.

If the rails app is using the correct username password, but not providing the other credentials, it could return this error instead.